# printf number format for constant width lat/long in exiftool

Tags: perl, printf, exiftool

Apparently I am misunderstanding the printf man page.  (Or else it's a bug in exiftool 10.55 and 10.77)

I am trying to get GPS coordinates from image files with [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).  I would like to make them the same width and without unnecessary spaces.

The format string I tried, and one of the results:

```
-coordFormat "%03d°%02d′%0d%02.5f″"
042°37′280.00000″ N, 002°05′510.00000″ W
```

(I don't need five decimal places—I just put that in temporarily to see whether any of the cameras wer being dishonest about the precision.)  The three unnecessary spaces can't be helped; they are outside the format string’s control, but I did get rid of others that were in the default.  The leading zero for latitude isn't needed, but it is there because longitude uses the same format string.  One problem is the bogus zero inserted between floor(seconds) and its decimal point.  The other problem is the false fractional part.  The default format for that file is `42 deg 37' 28.39" N, 2 deg 5' 51.96" W`

Someone's "[cheat sheet](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet)" said that my second digit should be the **total** width, including the decimal point, so I changed the seconds to "%08.5f" but all that did was add another bogus zero in front of the decimal point, e.g., 510.00000→5100.00000 (width of ten, not eight!).

A few years ago, I did something similar, and got the correct results.  But I didn't bother to save the script "for future reference."

(Several other [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273607/about-printf-format-string-in-c) agree with that "cheat sheet.")

Comment: What do you intend by `%0d`?

Comment: Forces leading zeros instead of spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the *seconds* field, for which you have the format specifier `%0d%02.5f`. I'm not sure what you intended, but there can be only one `%` for each value to be rendered

If you're formatting longitude then you are dealing with values between -180 and 180. If you want five decimal points then the total width will be

- One character for the sign `+` or `-`
- Three characters for the integer part
- One character for the decimal point `.`
- Five fractional digits

giving a total field width of ten. Your full specifier will be `%0+10.5f`, giving output between «-180.00000» and «+180.00000»

You may use a space flag instead of the `+`, as in `%0 10.5f`, which will use a space instead of a `+` to indicate a positive number, rendering 180 as « 180.00000». The leading zero is there so that zeroes are use to fill the full ten character field with

When dealing with latitude, you will need a total width one character smaller. `%0+9.5f` will result in a range of «-90.00000» to «+90.00000». Of course you may use the same format specifier as for longitude, which will produce «-090.00000» to «+090.00000». This way the latitude and longitude seconds will have the same number of characters

Comment: Aha!  I didn’t see that extra %0d—typo.  I did not intend for that to be there!  Thanks!  On the width point, exiftool uses one format string for both, unfortunately.  And it doesn’t need the sign because it puts the compass point after.

Comment: But the degrees won’t have a decimal part.  So the only error is the extra %0d

Comment: @WGroleau: Okay. The sign flag is either a `+` to show `+` / `-` for positive / negative numbers or a space to show space / `-`. If you don't want anything added for a positive value then don't use either of these. So `%0+10.5f` becomes `%010.5f`. If you want fewer fractional digits then reduce both the 10 and the 5 by the same amount, for instance `%07.2f` will give two decimal places.

Comment: The leading zero is because sometimes they will be sorted as strings instead of numbers.

Comment: @WGroleau: I assumed it was something like that. But if you prefer you can leave it out, which will give you spaces as padding instead. The result will still be sorted correctly.

Comment: True.  I forgot that “ “ is smaller than “0”

Answer (score 0):

The `%0d` is throwing you off. That part of the template is consuming the "51.0" seconds component of the coordinate, leaving nothing for the `%02.5d` part of the template.

```
printf "%0d", 51         ===>   "51"
printf "%02.5f";         ===>   "0.00000"

printf "%0d%02.5f", 51   ===>   "510.00000"
```

So lose the `%0d`.

The `2` in `%02.5f` also doesn't do you any good. The number before the decimal place is the minimum length of the field, and the number after the decimal place is the number of decimal places to use. Since 5 decimal places will be printed, the output will be at least 7 characters, and the `2` value will be ignored.

Comment: Your answer was partly based on a typo in the third from end paragraph, which is now fixed.

Answer (score -2):

First number is the width, second number is the number of decimal points so what you have currently (`%2.5f`) appears to be backwards. `%5.2f` would give you a number that occupies 5 characters and has 2 decimal places. For a number as big as 510, you probably want to make it `%6.2f`

Comment: As I said, I _did_ want five decimal places (temporarily).  And the seconds of any latitude or longitude are _never_ "510."  The correct value is "51" as I also stated.   Did you read the entire thing?

Comment: Yes, I read the whole thing - if you want 5 decimal places, you want the first number to be bigger than 5 then - `%8.5f` for example

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I wrote that I had tried that, but somehow wrote it wrong.  Edited to fix.